# How to import Leads that only exist in Salesforce, and ignore new Leads?

Tags: leads, import, data-import-wizard

I have a CSV file with a number of records that I periodically upload to Salesforce to update my Leads,

Unfortunately some of those records don’t exist in Salesforce,

And I don’t want Salesforce to automatically create new records,

It will be very time consuming for me to remove those records from the CSV file before

uploading to Salesforce,

How can I only upload the records that only have an existing record in Leads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where does your CSV come from?

Probably easiest is to export a report out of Salesforce (including the Id column), apply changes there (in Excel?) and import back the updates by Id.

If you have any unique field on the Leads (something that identifies them in external system? Email? anything?) you could mark that field as external Id and then either update only the ones that are found or use an operation called "upsert" that will look at this Id, at the existing data and determine whether record should be updated or created.

---

**Edit**

No, upsert is not only an Apex command. Data Loader has it too for example. It might be bit cumbersome in the beginning but I prefer it more than click-click-click of the wizards...

In import wizard select something here:

[image]

And then on page 2 you'll see this:

[image]

More info - for example http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_import_general_update_with_import_wizard.htm
I have to say that I found also the online (flash) trainings around import wizard pretty useful. They were ancient (recorded with old SF interface) but nonetheless they showed me that Data Loader & other API tools or "just quickly hack something with Apex" isn't always the easiest choice ;) I think there are separate movies for admin's wizard and the wizard available to end users... If you don't see the trainings in your Help - might be related to the edition you're on.

As far as I know import wizard will not respect your external Id fields, will only display the Id, Name and Email in the selection. So if you have ext. id and wish to match by it - you'll have to start using Data Loader's update or upsert operation.

There are plenty of options really:

1. You could play with VLOOKUPs in Excel to compose a final CSV that will contain only the matched info.
2. You could say "screw it, import them all" (so everything will fly in, both the matched updates as well as new leads) and then `delete[SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE CreatedDate > 2014-01-13T22:18:00Z AND CreatedBy.Name = 'My Name' LIMIT 10000];`. This will of course have some side effects if you for example send email notifications about new lead but you could always turn them temporarily off.

Comment: So that’s what I did originally, I download the Salesforce ID, but we did not want to keep track of all that information and store all those files,
How can I update only the external ID using the import wizard? The “upsert” operation, thats an APEX command, how can I use that through the import wizard? Can you please (if possible) provide a link with any documentation?

Comment: Well i am importing by email. i can easily find out the new Leads that are created through reports, and i can delete them one by one, but i guess i dont want to import them n the first place, but thnx for the info

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I know this thread is a bit old, but was keen to give an update on the best way to import leads periodically. We initially wrote our own code in Apex but was a nightmare to maintain, so we decided to use [Parserr](https://parserr.com). Its an online tool which helps you parse incoming emails and attachments.

As I said in my other post, we had to extract row data (lead per row) from Excel using Parserr. But they do email parsing too.

Full disclosure - through talking to the founder of the business, Im happy to vouch for them and help them along. Which is what Im doing here.